# python code to remove every n number of objects from json data

Tags: python, json

I have json response from an api which returns hourly data.
That is it returns 24 json objects for every day, but i only want the 24th object of each day and delete the rest.
how would i do this.

**Small json sample for reference**

```
    "data": [{
        "date": "Apr 01 2022",
        "volume": 75,
        "users": 26,
        "trades": 43,
        "fee": 0,
        "shared_fee": 0
    }, 
.
.
.
.
.
    {
        "date": "Apr 01 2022",
        "volume": 151,
        "users": 35,
        "trades": 305,
        "fee": 0,
        "shared_fee": 0
    },  {
        "date": "Apr 02 2022",
        "volume": 42,
        "users": 13,
        "trades": 25,
        "fee": 0,
        "shared_fee": 0
    }, 
.
.
.
.
    {
        "date": "Apr 02 2022",
        "volume": 130,
        "users": 26,
        "trades": 114,
        "fee": 0,
        "shared_fee": 0
    },
```

Comment: You can just get the last one with `last = response['data'][-1]` and disregard the rest.

Comment: what about using slicing `response_data['data'][23::24]`? the 24th object is at index 23, then with slicing and step=24 you take every 24th

Comment: but i want to do it for every 24th object not just the first

Comment: What user @buran suggests will get you the 24th object and every 24th after it. `response['data'][23::24]` is the correct answer. The first item is at index 23, the stride of the slice is 24, and there's no number between the `:`, indicating you want all instances.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your json file as a list containing dictionaries.
So, you can access it in two ways:

1. api_response["data"][-1] : this will return the value at last index
2. api_response["data"][23] : this will return the value at 23 index.( since index range starts from 0, so index of 24th item is 23)

Note :
api_response["data"][23::24] -> this will return list of element